# How to change the text colour to red in second row using the div class in css?

Tags: html, css

```
enter code here

 <div class="test"> 
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
 </div>
```

I tried to change the text color of second paragraph tag only to red using the test class

But I don't know how to do that without having an tr or td here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to select nth item from a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811839/how-to-select-nth-item-from-a-css-selector)

Comment: How would you do it if it were a `table` (with `tr` and `td`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-child()` selector to achieve this:

Some more answers here if you want to understand it further [nth child selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811839/how-to-select-nth-item-from-a-css-selector)`

```css
.test p:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
    div.test p:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="test"> 
  <p>One</p>
   <p>Two</p>
   <p>Three</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).